(Windows10) How to Keep Files & Settings if Company Domain is Deactivated?
I currently log into my computer using an Active Directory account, linked to Company A.
Company A has been acquired, so the CompanyA.com domain will soon be deactivated.  I will then not be able to log into my computer, despite having exactly the same job.
How can I retain access to all of my files and settings, when the domain is deactivated?
The person in control of the domain is willing to assist, but we have not been able to find a way to convert a domain account into a local account.

This is question to your IT department. They, and only they, can give you instructions for the transition. Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are explicitly off-topic here. See help center

Normally this would be handled by the IT staff.

We don't have an IT Department.  CompanyA "IT" is essentially one person, who is not particularly technical.  Ironically, I am in a more technical role than them. @ChanganAuto

@James - It's possible to migrate active directory users to another domain. This can only be acomplished by an Administrator on both domains. It does not sound like you are an Administrator on either domain.

You can't convert the whole user account (as local accounts need to have a local SID and that's the difficult part), but you can use various migration tools (mostly third-party) to back up all data and restore it into a different profile. I found suggestions on Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/nnrzgn/best_tool_to_migrate_user_profile_data/ suggests Forensit or USMTGUI.

The process isn't really needed for regular files (someone with local Administrator rights can just move them to a local account's Desktop and change ownership), but one of those tools should be able to handle general Registry export as well as the isolated settings of UWP/Appx apps.
(If it weren't for UWP apps, then it would have been doable easily without any tools other than icacls and regedit, but as of Win8 the old manual process unfortunately breaks things.)
At work when doing the opposite conversion (local to AD), there often wasn't much customization, so we just moved user files – including the Firefox profile – by hand into a clean account and updated ACLs using icacls /setowner.

However, while I haven't dealt with AD mergers, I believe AD does have a method to convert an account from one domain into an account from another domain – by setting up a temporary forest trust between the two AD domains, then moving the user account entries from one domain to another using ADMT (if that still exists?) so that they retain their old SID as "SID History". (A local account cannot keep SID history, but a domain account can, so your moved AD account would automatically retain access to the old profile – at least that's how I understand it should work.)
